# How to make my we crawler solve a wikipedia game faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm making a wikipedia crawler but it's very slow. How can I make it faster?

I'm using requests module and beautifulsoup4 to parse the html pages. I've tried implementing multithreading but it's still slow.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from queue import Queue

baseURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org";

startURL = "/wiki/French_battleship_Courbet_(1911)"
endURL = "/wiki/Royal_Navy"

tovisit = Queue()
visited = []

def main():


    if (not checkValid(startURL)) or (not checkValid(endURL)):
        print("Invalid URLs entered.")
        quit()

    initCrawler(startURL)

def initCrawler(startURL):

    global tovisit
    global visited

    tovisit.put(startURL)

    finished = False

    while not finished:

        if tovisit.empty():
            finished = True
            continue

        url = tovisit.get()

        childlinks = linkCrawl(url)

        for i in childlinks:
            tovisit.put(i)

        visited.append(url)

def linkCrawl(url):

    global visited
    global tovisit
    global endURL

    print("crawling "+ url + "\n")

    r = requests.get(baseURL+url)
    soup = bs(r.content, "html.parser")

    rawlinks = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

    refinedlinks = []

    for rawLink in rawlinks:
        i = rawLink["href"]
        if i is None:
            continue
        # ensure what we have is a string
        if not (type(i) is str):
            continue
        # no poi
        if i in visited:
            continue
        if i in list(tovisit.queue):
            continue
        if not checkValid(i):
            continue
        if i == endURL:
            print("yay")
            exit()
        refinedlinks.append(i)

    return refinedlinks

def checkValid(url):
    if not url.startswith("/wiki/"):
        return False
    if url.startswith("/wiki/Special:"):
        return False
    if url.startswith("/wiki/Wikipedia:"):
        return False
    if url.startswith("/wiki/Portal:"):
        return False
    if url.startswith("/wiki/File:"):
        return False
    if url.endswith("(disambiguation)"):
        return False
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I expect the bot to run faster, but it's actually slow. Research says that eventually multithreading won't be enough.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Why is visited a list? If you used a dictionary, I bet that would speed things up a lot. List is NOT a good data structure for lookups. Try reading about python data structures a bit more before you go into writing a web crawler. You also read it well, even multi threading might not be enough at some point and you might need more than 1 machine for a serious crawler, but for starters, what you have should be enough. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102631/how-to-write-a-crawler

Comment: You can use Scrapy. Scrapy is a fast, open-source web crawling framework written in Python, used to extract the data from the web page with the help of selectors based on XPath. A fast high-level crawler. It has good balancing multithreading and Load balancing. https://scrapy.org/

Comment: Try use [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) + [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) This is a crawler [example](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/examples/legacy/crawl.py)